# How to keep the latest dataset if there are more than 1 datasets in one day

Tags: mysql

i have a table which is updated random more than once a day. Every update contains about 2000 rows. I want to keep the latest dataset per day and remove the more old rows. I constructed an example:

The table "date" contains:

```
+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| title | hhm   | hhm_sum | updated             |
+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| 74142 | 21525 | 5874136 | 2020-06-15 00:00:00 |
| 74142 |  5263 |    2145 | 2020-06-22 00:00:00 |
| 74142 | 21254 |   21458 | 2020-06-22 04:00:00 |
| 74142 | 21458 |    3652 | 2020-06-22 08:00:00 |
| 74142 |  2158 |    1257 | 2020-06-20 00:00:00 |
+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

With: `SELECT * FROM test.date WHERE updated > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 24 HOUR);`

i get the datasets for the last 24hours:

```
+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| title | hhm   | hhm_sum | updated             |
+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| 74142 |  5263 |    2145 | 2020-06-22 00:00:00 |
| 74142 | 21254 |   21458 | 2020-06-22 04:00:00 |
| 74142 | 21458 |    3652 | 2020-06-22 08:00:00 |
+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

I want to remove the older rows on the same day and keep the newest. How can i get and handle this value?

Maybe anyone can help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show us what you've tried by [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62521489/edit), please, as well as a sample of the rows you want to keep and the rows you don't. Finally, what is the type of `updated`?

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you have to specofy what are the oldest, the oldest 10 , since afternoon, an example with data would  help

Comment: Or see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the single newest row, sort by `updated desc` and take the first row.

```
select *
from test_date
order by updated desc
limit 1
```

If there can be multiple rows which all have the newest `updated`, do a [subquery](https://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm) to get the `max(updated)`.

```
select *
from test_date
where updated = (
  select max(updated) from test_date
)
```